# Detect Specific script's event fire

Tags: c#

I have a third party script UIDragResize which contains an event called OnDrag. I want to know a programmable way (without changing the original script) to track if the OnDrag event is firing so that i can run my code.

```
if (specific script's onDrag run)
 then do this
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a dll or exe of that third party library than I would suggest that you hook up a event listener on that particular event in the instance of that class which fires this event to listen for it and to act appropriately.

Your question is lacking detail, so I cannot give a exact solution or a proper answer to it.
Maybe give us some sample code in which you use the third party component and maybe give us more insight in how you can access it.

Comment: i have that script, it is actually third party

Comment: So...Can you access the namespaces/classes of it inside your C# application or is it not compatible with .NET?

Comment: Well if the class is firing the event and you can create an instance of it just hook up an event listener like for example 'new UIDragResize().OnDrag+=Event_Handler' where Event_Handler is a delegate of a existing method which matches the events parameters.
This helpful [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) may help you to understand events in C#.